# Android Admob Mediation : How can i listen for interstitial ad events when using mediation?

Tags: android, kotlin, admob, mobile-ad-mediation

I have searched the whole internet and didn't find any answer. Maybe someone in this community knows the answer. Here's what is happening...

When i normally use admob interstitial ad i can listen for ad events using the `adListener` like this,

```
mInterstitialAd.adListener = object : AdListener() {
        override fun onAdLoaded()  }

        override fun onAdFailedToLoad(adError: LoadAdError) {}

        override fun onAdOpened() {}

        override fun onAdClicked() {}

        override fun onAdLeftApplication() {}

        override fun onAdClosed()  }
    }
```

But i don't know if it will work the same way or not when i use multiple ad networks through Admob Mediation. In my case i am using `UnityAds` and `Facebook Audience Network` with `AdMob`. Before i was using these ad networks separately and i have used different `adListeners` for each ad network's interstitial ad.
Now my question is, Do i need to use different `adListeners` for each of these ad networks when using `mediation`? If so, how can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you need a separate implementation for handling Mediated Ad Events. You need to add the 3rd party Ad Network Keys in Admob Mediation Settings and continue. Admob will randomly pick Interstitial Ads from different network, based on the priority you have given in Admob Settings.